# How to eliminate repeating code patterns when processing line-oriented data?

Tags: c++, logic, c++17

Often, when processing some line-oriented data files, I find myself writing this pattern of code:

```
while (std::getline(infile, line))
{           
    if (line.compare("")) 
    {
        //Process non-empty line
    }
    else 
    {
        //Finalize processing a group of non-empty lines
    }
}

if (infile.eof())
{
    //Finalize processing a group of non-empty lines
}
```

The example above illustrates, that the processing of a group of non-empty lines is finalized when encountering an empty line or the end of file/stream.

I would appreciate suggestions how to optimize this code sequence and avoid the identical `Finalization Code` appearing in the code TWICE ...or avoid checking for eof **twice** every loop iteration.

P.S.
I do not want the `Finalization Code` to run when a hardware read error occurs - in other words, the eof and a read error should not be conflated.

[image]

Comment: code reuse!  Functional, template or classes. Whole snippet can be templated!

Comment: yeah you would just want to make a function for that. something like `processNonEmptyLines(std::string[] arr)` and pass the group when you need to process.

Comment: "*the eof and a read error should not be conflated.*" So, what *do* you want to do in case of a `failbit`?

Comment: If the `failbit` is not set by reaching the end of file, then I just want to exit the function and return an error code....without executing the `Finalization Code`.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
while (infile)
{      
    std::getline(infile, line);
    if (infile && line.compare("")) 
    {
        //Process non-empty line
    }
    else if (infile || infile.eof())
    {
        //Finalize processing a group of non-empty lines
    }
}
```

It's the logical equivalent of your code, but without the duplicate code, you get duplicate conditions as a trade-off.

Comment: ...but the duplicate conditions will be subject to short-circuit evaluation, won't they ?  Also, what will happen if eof is not reached but read error occurs ?

Comment: @GeorgeRobinson "short-circuit" as in if part of the condition is not true the rest won't be evaludated is not very relevant in this case but your compiler might sue some optimizations if the code is as simple as in this case. And for your second question, the same thing that in your original code, nothing.

Answer (score 0):

You can have the loop only abort on non-EOF errors and then manually exit the loop on EOF after processing the group of non-empty lines:

```
while (std::getline(infile, line) || infile.eof())
{
    if (infile.eof() || line.compare(""))
    {
        // Finalize processing a group of non-empty lines.
    }
    else if (infile.eof())
    {
        // We're done.
        break;
    }
    else
    {    
        // Process non-empty line.
    }
}
```

You are checking for EOF three times, but that's cheap and insignificant compared to the processing work the loop does.